# How Can I get a list of all StreamSubscriptions from the stream

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I have a `Stream` which is listened by `StreamProvider`.

**Question is how to get list of all `subscribers` of the one particular `Stream`.(let's say it is a `broadcastStream`).**

I don't need something like this:

```
StreamSubscription streamSub = stream.listen((){});
```

**I need a list of subscribers of a stream to access them one by one.**

I hope there is someone who knows answer for that, thank you in advance.
I tried so many things it is not worth mentioning here. sorry about that.

I need something like this notice the `getSubscribers()` function:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {

  StreamController streamControlloer = StreamController();
  Stream stream = streamControlloer.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  
  // create subscribers
  StreamSubscription sub1 = stream.listen((event){});
  
  StreamSubscription sub2 = stream.listen((event){});
  
  StreamSubscription sub3 = stream.listen((event){});
  
  StreamSubscription sub4 = stream.listen((event){});
  
  // grab all of the subscribers
  List<StreamSubscription> subscribers = stream.getSubscribers();
  
  // pause with grabbed subscribers
  subscribers[0].pause();
  subscribers[1].pause();

  // resume with grabbed subscribers
  subscribers[1].resume();
  subscribers[1].resume();
  
}
```

Comment: "normal" `Stream` does not provide such featue - you would need to wrap your `Stream` with a custom class extending `Stream` and overriding `listen` method

Comment: @pskink Thank you for answer, from this point your answer makes sense.
Would you be so kind to write an answer where you will say what you would write in overriden listen method. it is not neccessary to be detailed

Comment: something like `class FooStream extends Stream {
final Stream original;

FooStream(this.original);

@override
StreamSubscription listen(void onData(event), {Function onError, void onDone(), bool cancelOnError}) {
/* add it to the list */
return original.listen(onData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: cancelOnError);
}
}` - also you would need to provide a custom `onDone` to know when the stream is done and you need to remove it from the list

Comment: I am looking for the result like this notice getSubscribers() function in code 
https://codeshare.io/5zBwe4

Comment: I have updated the question so you will be able to view it here too